# ActionMailer authenticate with gmail to send email without using unsecure apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail

Hello i am trying to send emails (through gmails gsuite with a custom domain) through a rails 5 app using action mailer but while using the configuration recommended here:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

it also says to setup unsecure apps but we use two factor auth and it wont let us setup unsecure apps here is what it shows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0WKn.png)

I have also gone down the path of setting up an app password and used that with the result of:

```
Error performing ActionMailer::Parameterized::DeliveryJob (Job ID: <job id> from Async(mailers) in 1543.41ms: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
```

i have followed all the instructions in this section of the documentation with no success.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

So my question is this.

how do i configure the `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` so that i am able to send emails throught my gsuite email address that uses a custom domain name

Comment: You should be able to add an application password even if the account requires mfa.

Comment: how are you entering that username and password? In other words, where you've got '<username>' and '<password>'  are they literally just that in the file or do you have e.g. 'johnsmith' and 'mypassword'?